# Show JSON values in textview with Objective C iOS App

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I'm new to Objective C but I'm trying to get my JSON data to show in my textview that I declared. (The textview is called textview)  Here is my JSON data that is being sent from the PHP page:

```
{
  "userName": "derekshull",
  "userBio": "This is derekshulls bio",
  "userSubmitted": "15"
}
```

And here is my Objective C code that is requesting the PHP url and getting the JSON code:

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json.php"];

NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)myJSON;

for (id element in jsonArray) {
    textview.text = [NSLog(@"Element: %@", [element description])];            
}
```

The JSON is loading in the debug bank.  I have searched and searched for 3 days through stackoverflow and the internet and this is what I've come up with, but I don't understand why it's not printing to textview.

Comment: Does it print anything to the text view (one line)? You should add the error parameter and log it.

Comment: I've tried to look it up real quick.  Again I'm new.  How would I add a error parameter and log it with the code I have?  would it be this: `NSError *anyError;
    BOOL success = [NSLog(@"Element: %@", [element description])];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Write failed with error: %@", anyError);
        // present error to user
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json.php"];

NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if(!error)
{

  for (id element in jsonArray) {
     textview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Element: %@",element];   
     // text view will contain last element from the loop       
 }
}
else{
  textview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error description]];
 }
```

Comment: This did something!  It gave us the description of the data we are trying to get which was userName.  How do we get the value of that description though?

Comment: @user3093592 , please post "jsonArray" log. then i can only tell you. or give me a original url.

Comment: I posted that at the top of my question I believe.

Comment: @user3093592 sorry my mistake, in that case you dont need the description, but only the element. check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the JSON text in the text view then don't deserialize it with `NSJSONSerialization`, just drop the string straight in:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
textview.text = string;
```